# Confused about different ways of invoking action creators in React with Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm reading *Learning Redux* by Daniel Bugl (which by the way is outstanding) and in the "FilterList component" section code example there is an action creator invocation that looks like this:

```
onClick={() => setFilter(category)}
```

and one like this:

```
onClick={clearFilter}
```

So it looks like when there are no arguments invocation works with just function name and when there are arguments then a more verbose syntax, in this case the arrow function syntax needs to be used. I'd like to verify this with the community here.

If I can do `clearFilter` just like that then why can't I do `setFilter(category)` without the arrow function syntax?

Answer (score 1):

`myFunction` is a reference to a specific function, which can be passed around, assigned to a variable, etc. `myFunction(...)` is a *call* to a function. If you try to pass that, you'll be passing whatever that function call returned.

You can't do `setFilter(category)` because you'd be passing the result of that function call, not the function itself. That's why you wrap the call in an anonymous [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) (`() => {...}`, where the curly braces are optional for simple functions), and pass that in.

While not specific to ES6 or React, you'd probably find it useful to [learn more about JavaScript functions over at MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions).

Comment: Focus on the fundamentals of the language and you will understand what is going.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's the difference between *passing a reference* to a function and *calling* a function.  Remember that JSX gets transformed into a call to `React.createElement()`, and props get turned into an object.  Here's how it looks:

```
    // before
<SomeComponent 
    onClick1={clearFilter}
    onClick2={() => setFilter(category)}
    onClick3={setFilter(category)}
/>

// after
React.createElement(SomeComponent, {
    onClick1 : clearFilter,
    onClick2 : () => setFilter(category),
    onClick3 : setFilter(category)
});
```

For `onClick1`, we're passing a reference to a named function.  For `onClick2`, we're passing a reference to an anonymous function that calls another function when it runs.  But, for `onClick3`, we're *calling* `setFilter(category)` *as we render*, and then using the *result* of that as the value for `onClick3`.  That's *not* what you want.

Also, note that this actually has nothing to do with Redux and action creators.  It's actually just about React, JSX, and how functions work in Javascript.

Comment: In both cases the desired effect is function invocation which changes a variable. clearFilter always changes category to the same thing ('all' I think) so it does not need an argument. setFilter(category) needs to be able to assign different strings to the category variable thus the function argument. It looks like when a function invocation requires no arguments a reference is all React needs to know that onClick it needs to invoke that function whereas if the function needs argument(s) passed to it then the anonymous function syntax is required.

Comment: Not exactly.  In _both_ cases, a function reference is required.  However, `onClick={someFunc(someArg)}` is going to _call_ `someFunc()`, so `onClick` is going to be given whatever `someFunc()` returns.  Unless `someFunc()` returns a new function, `onClick` won't get a function reference.  However, `{() => someFunc(someArg)}` _is_ a function reference, so that will work okay.